# Executing indexes concurrently. Any negatives?

Tags: magento2.4, reindex, cli, command-line, indexer

Because reindexing takes so long, I am contemplating running several reindex commands concurrently, via the CLI, see below:

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product & php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_category & php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute & php bin/magento indexer:reindex cataloginventory_stock & php bin/magento indexer:reindex inventory catalog_product_price & php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext &`

Can anyone find any issue with this approach?